# conditional input to playbook based on vars_prompt - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a situation where depending on the user input with vars_prompt specific set of commands in the playbook task need to be executed. With the above options input A, B, C specific commands associated with that option need to be executed. All the commands are there in a single task.

- A - ipaddr
- B - ifconfig
- C - freespace -m , yum repolist

```
    vars_prompt:
          - name: input
            prompt: Please enter the option A,B,C
            private: no
        
        - name: checking the switchshow
           value_command:
           command_set:
            - command: ipaddr
            - command: ifconfig
            - command: freespace -m
            - command: yum repolist
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question? What have you tried? What is not working as expected? Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: @toydarian I am looking for the suggestion on how to solve this use case. Can this be achieved with when condition?

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I could understand that you want to run specific commands as per user input of A, B, or C. The code snippet is not so clear about it though.

So let's say we want to conditionally run commands:

When user types option:

- A: run `ipaddr` command
- B: run `ifconfig` command
- C: run `freespace -m` and `yum repolist`

Then we can have a playbook like below:

```yaml
  vars_prompt:
  - name: input
    prompt: "Please enter the option A,B,C"
    private: false

  tasks:
  - name: run ipaddr
    command: "ipaddr"
    when: input == "A"
  - name: run ifconfig 
    command: "ifconfig"
    when: input == "B"
  - block:
    - name: run freespace -m 
      command: "freespace -m"
    - name: run yum repolist 
      command: "yum repolist"
    when: input == "C"
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but I have a module value _command. I need to pass them with that module. The command which I gave like ifconfig, yum repolist are just the example. But there is a different set of command need to be run on network switch.